# Hide upload button when image is present, Show when Image is gone?

Tags: jquery, hide, show

This is such an easy question, but for the life of me cannot get my solution to work, I have fiddled for a while now and am coming up slightly short, I feel like an idiot.

http://jsfiddle.net/N8pCq/292/

Ill get straight into the code

JQuery:

```
    $('#_moon_static_bg_status').on('change',function(){ 

       var image_status =$('#test').hasClass('static_preview_image'),
           upload_button = $(".moon_upload_button");

            if (image_status){ 
               upload_button.hide(); 
            } else {
               upload_button.show();
            }

    }).trigger('change');
```

Simply put I just want to show the upload button based on whether the class .static_preview_image exisits, this class contains the image, when a user closes the image the whole div is removed, so I figured calling for that class would be good for showing and hiding, because when its not there we show the upload, when the image is shown we hide the upload button.

HTML:

```
     <div class="moon_media_status" id="_moon_static_bg_status">

     <input type="button" value="Upload File" class="moon_upload_button button"></input>

     <a rel="_moon_static_bg" class="moon_remove_file_button" href="#">Remove Image</a>

     <div id="test" class="static_preview_image"></div>

     </div>
```

when .moon_remove_file_button is clicked the div you see under it .static_preview_image is removed completely, when user uploads an image the div with .static_preview_image comes back, so naturally we would want to remove that button and only expose the close button...

Thinking back I could see how the open source jQuery removes the .moon_remove_file_button and copy that, but since I wrote this up id like to see where I am making the brain fart mistake...

Again here is the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/N8pCq/292/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the change event on click of remove button so that the logic re-applies.

```
$('.moon_remove_file_button').click(function(){
    $('#test').removeClass('static_preview_image');
    $('#_moon_static_bg_status').change();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7VUV/)**

Comment: oh okay, my problem was the remove button function was already established in the live code (in my project), I threw that code in the fiddle so my if else statement would work similar to the real code, but I find though this is indeed what I need, I added a function for the upload button in this fiddle as well, nothing special but now we have complete functionality http://jsfiddle.net/h7VUV/1/

Comment: its the simple stuff that frustrates me im still working on getting better, I took on jQuery about a month or so ago... hallelujah for this site, makes my work flow much easier.. thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry You are welcome. :) you will get there soon.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use javascript for this, simply hide the image with CSS.  This will change your markup a bit, but you can also use positioning to achieve the look you're going for (or use right-to-left positioning to reverse the order.  An example of that can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/)).

HTML:

```
<div class="moon_media_status" id="_moon_static_bg_status">
    <a rel="_moon_static_bg" class="moon_remove_file_button" href="#">Remove Image</a> 
    <div id="test" class="static_preview_image"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Upload File" class="moon_upload_button button" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.moon_remove_file_button').click(function(){
    $('#test').removeClass('static_preview_image');
});

$('.moon_upload_button').click(function () {
    $('#test').addClass('static_preview_image');
});
```

CSS:

```
.static_preview_image {
    height: 500px; 
    width: 500px; 
    background-image: url(http://themes.moonrocketstudio.com/brash/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/bur.jpg);}

.static_preview_image ~ .moon_upload_button{
    display: none;
}
```

**Edit**

Demo here: http://jsbin.com/ozades/1/edit

Comment: Hmm interesting angle, much easier, the background image is actually an inline style because I am using jQuery to add the image based on what the user uploads, irrelevant though this solution would still work.

Comment: Wait taking a second glance wouldnt the upload button still be visable?

It's not an issue of hiding the image because we remove that block when user closes the image, then an upload button is displayed, when user clicks that chooses image media we display the image again while hiding the upload button

Comment: The upload button stays visable